# Why does my random forest and decision tree keep displaying 100% accuracy?

Tags: python, keras

I am at a standstill because my output keeps displaying 100% accuracy on both random forest and decision tree but not support vector machine

I beleive the issue resides on how the data is either trained or tested. I think it is testing on the training data and not the testing data. However, I have no idea how to fix it.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
import seaborn as sns
import warnings
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

heart_data = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')

heart_data.head()
y = heart_data.target.values
x_data = heart_data.drop(['target'], axis = 1)
x = (x_data - np.min(x_data)) / (np.max(x_data) - np.min(x_data)).values
n_cols = x.shape[1]

#Splitting Data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20)




def regression_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    #inputs
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu')) # activation function
    model.add(Dense(1))

    # compile model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    #loss measures the results and figures out how bad it did. Optimizer generates next guess.
    return model


# build the model
model = regression_model()
print (model)
# fit the model
history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test,y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=10)



# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

#Decision Tree
print ("Processing Decision Tree")
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc.fit(x_test,y_test)
print("Decision Tree Test Accuracy {:.2f}%".format(dtc.score(x_test, y_test)*100))


#Support Vector Machine
print ("Processing Support Vector Machine")
svm = SVC(random_state = 1)
svm.fit(x_test, y_test)
print("Test Accuracy of SVM Algorithm: {:.2f}%".format(svm.score(x_test,y_test)*100))

#Random Forest
print ("Processing Random Forest")
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 1)
rf.fit(x_test, y_test)
print("Random Forest Algorithm Accuracy Score : {:.2f}%".format(rf.score(x_test,y_test)*100))
```

I am hopeing to get +90% on the random forest. Any syntax advice or changes are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once, you already asked this question yesterday, and the comments already pointed you to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should train your model with x_train and y_train, and validate them with the test data.

For example:

```
#Random Forest
print ("Processing Random Forest")
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 1000, random_state = 1)
rf.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_test_pred = rf.predict(x_test)
print("Random Forest Algorithm Accuracy Score : {:.2f}%".format(rf.score(x_test,y_test)*100))
```